# How to SUM every NON-NULL entry from last 7 days?

Tags: mysql, database

Using PHP, PDO, and MySQL8 on a LAMP stack.  Testing queries with Adminer.

I have a database like this:

```
+------------+----------------+------+--------+--------+--------+
| DATE       | CLIENT         |AM1200| AM1230 | AM0100 | AM0130 | ...... (etc, for every 30 mins in a 24 hour day)
+------------+----------------+------+--------+--------+--------+
| 2020-06-20 | tx1.server.com | ER13 | NULL   | NULL   | OK     | ......
| 2020-06-20 | tx2.server.com | OK   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | ......
| 2020-06-20 | tx3.server.com | OK   | OK     | OK     | OK     | ......
| 2020-06-20 | tx4.server.com | OK   | OK     | OK     | OK     | ......
| 2020-06-20 | tx5.server.com | UNK  | UNK    | NULL   | NULL   | ......
| 2020-06-21 | tx1.server.com | OK   | OK     | OK     | UNK    |  ......
| 2020-06-21 | tx2.server.com | NULL | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | ......
| 2020-06-21 | tx3.server.com | OK   | OK     | OK     | OK     | ......
| 2020-06-21 | tx4.server.com | OK   | OK     | OK     | OK     | ......
| 2020-06-21 | tx5.server.com | NULL | NULL   | OK     | OK     | ......
```

I need to count the total number of NON-NULL values for each "Client" over the last 7 days.  End result should be something like this:

```
+----------------+----------------+
| CLIENT         | TOTAL NON-NULL |
+----------------+----------------+
| tx3.server.com | 336            |
| tx4.server.com | 328            |
| tx1.server.com | 281            |
| tx5.server.com | 269            |
| tx2.server.com | 42             |
```

New to MySQL, and I've tried probably 2 dozen different solutions found here on SO and the MySQL Dev Docs  but I'm unable to achieve my desired result.

Most of my attempts have yielded a count of ALL fields, whether they are NULL or not.

I think this (slightly abbreviated) query is my closest attempt thus far. But it's still not working properly for me.  It's giving me a count of all fields (NULL or not).

```
SELECT client, 
        SUM(IF(am1200=NULL,NULL,1) + IF(am1230=NULL,NULL,1) + IF(am0100=NULL,NULL,1) +  ....etc) AS Total
FROM `client_pings`
WHERE date >= `2020-06-15`
AND date <= `2020-06-23`
GROUP BY client
ORDER BY Total DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Normalize your data simply.

Comment: which "NON NULL" you want to count for each client?

Comment: unless the null in your data is a string the test for null should be is null not = null.and you should probably set to 0 if true eg IF(am1230 is null,0,1)

Comment: @Strawberry - Thank you for that. I'd never seen those mandates before... regardless, I think I did everything your post suggests except the CREATE / INSERT / Fiddle part.

Comment: @FachryDzaky - All the hourly and half-hourly checkpoints (e.g. AM1200 | AM1230 | AM0100 | AM0130 | etc. )

Comment: `except the CREATE / INSERT / Fiddle part``. That's pretty much the crux of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplified version of your data assuming null values and testing for null using is null

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(id int, am1 varchar(10),am2 varchar(10),am3 varchar(10));
insert into t values
(1,null,'maybe','nok'),
(2,'ok','maybe','nok')
;

select id,
         sum(if(am1 is null,0,1)+if(am2 is null,0,1)+if(am3 is null,0,1)) total
from t
group by id
order by total desc;

+------+-------+
| id   | total |
+------+-------+
|    2 |     3 |
|    1 |     2 |
+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: "IS NULL" is the solution I was seeking ... not the "= NULL" I was using.